# Can “strong” be implied?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I saw  the expression "the grass is greener".  I wondered if you can say that the grass is “very green”, but I think it means “having very strong green colour,” but “green” itself cannot have “very” in a literal sense. Is it correct?

For another example, “very bright” means “giving out very strong light.”

Comment: I am happy to speak of degrees of greenness. Green is a primary colour for light (thought not for paint) so there is a pure green, as well as shades where the green is barely visible.

Comment: I saw “very green” was used.  Can you tell us where you saw this? Please give the context.

Comment: @James K Actually, I saw “the grass is greener,” and it’s kinda derivative.

Comment: I don't really know how a "strong green" might be different to a "weak green". Perhaps what you're trying to say might be better expressed as *a very **vivid** green*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, exactly, I think “vivid” can be implicit in usage.

Comment: I've edited.  Please make sure that you give this context.  You didn't see "very green" but "greener".  I've tried to make that clear.

Comment: 'Green' is also used to refer to the pale face of a person who feels nauseous, so a seasick person might be described as looking 'very green'.

Comment: (After seeing edit) Dry grass is less green than healthy, well-watered grass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grass is greener (on the other side) is an idiom. It has a metaphorical meaning

Yes, we can say something is "greener": in the case grass, low quality grass might be a yellow-green or a brown-green.  Good grass is a strong green.

We don't often say "very green". It might mean "surprisingly green", and implying something is either "too green" or "exceptionally good and green".

> Your grass is very green! Do you use a fertiliser?

> Your room is *very* green.  I like the colour in a bathroom, but having green curtains, green carpet and bright green paint on the wall is too much!

In most contexts we would use a different modifier, like "bright green" or "pure green".